# How could I use not match pattern（?! ） regex in python

Tags: regex

There are three blocks in the next code,I want filter the block without **0x100**;As the code shows,I want to get   block B with 3 three section and without 0x100.But I try to use 
`ss=re.compile("/begin\s+(.*?(?!0x100).*?)/end",re.S)`,but it failed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzYDC.png)

```
import re
```

content ='''
/begin
    section A1

```
section A2
0x100
```

/end

/begin
    section B1

```
section B2

section B3
```

/end

/begin
    section C1

```
section C2
0x100
```

/end
'''
ss=re.compile("/begin\s+(.*(?!0x100).*)/end",re.S)
print ss.findall(content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to match from occurrence of `/begin` up until `/end` where there are no occurrences of `0x100`

```
ss=re.compile("/begin\s+((?:.(?!0x100))*?)/end",re.S)
```

With given example:

```
/begin section A1

section A2
0x100

/end

/begin section B1

section B2

section B3

/end

/begin section C1

section C2
0x100

/end
```

Will output:

```
['section B1\n\nsection B2\n\nsection B3\n\n']
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, now I understand  every character should not follow 0x100，and then any times like this character.